# Using mimetypes: How to use offset in magic?

Tags: linux, gnome, kde, mime-types, mime-headers

I know that to add a mimetype whose file extension is used for other mimetype I can use magic like that:

```
<mime-type type="audio/x-gtp">
    <magic priority="50">
        <match value="BCFZ" type="string" offset="0" />
    </magic>
    <glob pattern="*.gpx"/>
</mime-type>
```

This means that always the first four characters of *audio/x-gtp* file are `BCFZ`, and in effect it is so.

But with other file type (that is the same as .gpx but in other program version) whose file-extension is *.gp*, there is not a printable pattern at the beginning of the file.

I show you, the output of four first lines of *hexdump* of the *.gp* file:

```
hexdump -C /home/cactus/Descargas/arpeggio.gp  | head -4                                                                                                                                                  
00000000  50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |PK..............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 08 00 00 00 43 6f  |..............Co|
00000020  6e 74 65 6e 74 2f 50 4b  03 04 14 00 08 00 08 00  |ntent/PK........|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

As you can see, the first characters are not printable, so I want the pattern to be `Content/PK`. I think I can get to this character using *offset*, like `offset=10` but I don't know what represents the number, and how use it.

Thanks

Comment: just count, offset 29?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Finally it works with offset 30, like that `<match value="\x43\x6f\x6e\x74\x65\x6e\x74\x2f\x50\x4b\x03\x04\x14" type="string" offset="30"  />`

Comment: Yes, sure, zero based / 1 based .. always a bit of a gamble ;)